# Placing a non working icon or menu option in an application

Tags: usability, user-expectation, mvp

My CEO asks me to place in a MVP (alpha version of a product in production) icons for functionality that does not yet exist. Specifically a filter icon. This way he will be able to tell - when he shows it - that this functionality will be available soon.
Is that something that anyone seen?
I can design a message saying "This feature will be available on the next version/soon" on hovering/clicking, but I feel it's a bad UX, and I personally never seen that.
(I did see "locked" premium options, but not such misleading teasers).

Be happy to an advise if this is a big NO, even though the MVP version will be available only to a few.

Here's the specific case: since we do not have time to develop filters, they want a disabled icon. Off-course its better to provide some explanation why its disabled (even though you use disabled feature when something is temporarily disabled (no context, something user have to do), and not when functionality is not available...

[image]

Comment: I have seen "coming soon" messages done right (although I don't have an example at the moment). They can make a product (especially a MVP) more interesting to return to. But it is basically a promise that you make to the user so be careful how to communicate it. Clarity, honesty and accuracy (how soon is soon?) are key. Do you have an example of what it will look like?

Comment: I would wonder what the added value is of specifically showing the icon as a teaser, when it doesn't have any functionality yet. What is the goal here? Continue asking questions to find out what that is, so you can find an appropriate solution. If the goal is to announce a new feature, why would an announcement message not suffice?

Comment: @jazZRo updated with the example.  Thanks!!

Comment: @IrisGreen You should avoid typing "Thanks" as you did in the Q and in every single comment on every answer. Instead, you have the option to upvote any answer you like. Please have a look at the [Help Center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I’ve seen this.

Imho:

- It might be a good idea if you use it to measure interest in a feature
- It’s a horrible idea if you seriously want to promise a feature in an agile context

Putting coming-soon features into the product can be used to test hypothesises and user interest, to prioritise features in the next iterations.

In the [Lean UX book](https://leanuxbook.com/), this is explicitly suggested under the name of *Feature Fake (aka the Button to Nowhere)*.

Their example includes Flickr’s Apple TV app, which included a “Use as screensaver” button when viewing a photo album. That button would open a dialog explaining

> Screensaver functionality is not available at this time
> Flickr will be updated with screensaver support as soon as possible

---

Then, on the other hand, actually promising a feature is problematic in an agile context, where we’re less following a plan than responding to change.

Chances are, you wont deliver the feature at all. Working in agile made me realise at some point that while you should embrace iteration and rework, you should strive to release a quality increment each sprint.

**So if you’re not using the fake feature to learn something, do not do it.**

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. I would not be able to learn my metrics, since this is installed on premise. Another thing - for such a basic feature it feels more like - we very much wanted to have a filter, but developers did not had the time so it will be there, soon. :-(

Comment: Then it falls under the second part: It’s not a good idea (;

Answer (score 0):

This could go very wrong and might end up frustrating lot of users and lot of work for support team.

I guess this idea is too much influenced from webpages to create hype around a website or a product. Not available feature adds no value to the user, it should be highlighted on the page etc with detail around this feature or big new feature coming soon (which filter is not)

This is not solving any problem instead customer calling support to know the what this feature is about, launch date, why it is there if not launch etc,  this only peaks their curiosity without any resolve.

Though to soften the blow hovering on this mvp icon if release date and bit info is mentioned then it might be ok but not having will be best as filter is basic feature these day for users and nothing to give sneak-peak.

Comment: Thanks @Vicktor_IV ... That's what I thought, but sometimes when product or management insist on an problematic feature, you start doubting that maybe you are being too stubborn...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad idea. **To have an interface element that doesn't work is basically... Having an interface element that doesn't work**. There's no other way to put it. If you confuse users and, what's worse, if you bother them with features that don't exist, then you'll definitely lose users.

## However...

**...context is everything.** What I mentioned above I think should apply to any general case. But you mention a very specific detail that changes things somehow. In this case it's the word **"MVP"**.

**First things first:** I'm not going to get into the *"we didn't have time to build a filtering feature"* for an MVP that hasn't been released yet. It should take a few hours to do this in any language, and on top of that, most languages have plug-and-play libraries. You'll know the reasons for this, but I think you might consider asking the question: "Is it really THAT HARD, to implement such a feature?". Maybe they're not doing it because nobody asked for it, it's a quite trivial feature.

Back to the MVP: as long as it's not used by real users, it's OK.

The most common cases for MVPs are to **show the system to stakeholders, to attract investors, to test some parts of the system in its final environment,** etc. However, if you want to use it for testing, **you need to remove features that don't work**. The alpha version is there for testing, so what's the point of showing disabled features? It'll obviously give you bad results in any user testing heuristic.

## In short

If it's a limited MVP, you can use this *"fake"* feature. If it's alpha, it depends on your conception of alpha. If it's the *"in-house"* conception, then it's more or less the same as MVP, so again, you can use it. **Anything bigger than beta is a big no-no.**

Comment: Thanks for such elaborated answer. It's an Alpha. It will be used partially in-house (our employees sitting in customer site), but sad truth is that 1) its a basic feature 2) We got 2 weeks to develop this so it went out soon due the various flow complexities 3) its is so basic I feel this disabled icon serves almost as an apology.  its not there really for a good reason besides demoing it a little, but in the same time you can present a slide stating the next features.

Comment: It‘s not a real MVP if it’s not used by real users. It fails its main objective: To learn from actual use. If it was done right, we’d have way better UX in most products (:

Comment: @IrisGreen in that case I don't see a problem. Since it will be prople form your own organization, you can let testers know why that feature is not ready yet

Comment: Interesting question: Is it really testers? Aren’t they supposed to work with the MVP? Also, not all users will receive the message or the initial schooling, from my experience. Gradually more and more users will be added, not being aware of every feature that‘s “coming soon”. So it stays a disturbing point of frustration, especially when reality hits and the team never gets around to implement that feature.

Comment: @Andy, as I said, if this is for the general public, it should not be used. For an MVP (which by definition will never reach a general audience) there is no problem as it is tested internally. It is very easy (and common) to explain to your own employees why something is not as it should be because your own company is still working on it. e.g.: We are testing a Figma prototype for a company with thousands of users, and obviously most of the features do not work, but their own users understood that without us having to tell them. They failed and said "ah, it's a WIP".